# Explicit type conversion?

Tags: haskell, types

This is an example function:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LAZ
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as CHA
import Network.Wreq

makeRequest :: IO (Network.Wreq.Response LAZ.ByteString)
makeRequest = do 
   res <- get "http://www.example.com" 
   let resBody = res ^. responseBody :: CHA.ByteString
   --Do stuff....
   return (res)
```

I'm struggling to understand the exact purpose of CHA.ByteString in this line:

```
let resBody = res ^. responseBody :: CHA.ByteString
```

Is this explicitly stating the type must be CHA.ByteString? Or does it serve another role?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is just explicitly stating that the type must be `CHA.ByteString`. This does (by itself) *not* incur any sort of conversion, it's just a hint for the compiler (and/or the reader) that `res` must have this type.

These kinds of local annotations are needed when a value is both produced from a function with *polymorphic result*, and only consumed by functions with polymorphic argument. A simple example:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f = fromEnum . toEnum
```

Here, [`toEnum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:toEnum) converts an integer to a arbitrary enumerable type – could for instance be `Char`. Whatever type you'd choose, `fromEnum` would be able to convert it back... trouble is, there is no way to decide which type should be used for the intermediate result!

```
No instance for (Enum a0) arising from a use of ‘fromEnum’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  instance Enum Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
  instance Enum Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
  ...plus 7 others
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fromEnum’
In the expression: fromEnum . toEnum
In an equation for ‘f’: f = fromEnum . toEnum
```

For some simple number classes, Haskell has *defaults*, so e.g. `fromIntegral . round` will automatically use `Integer`. But there are no defaults for types like `ByteString`, so with a polymorphic-result function like [`responseBody`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:responseBody), you either need to pass the result to a monomorphic function that *can* only accept `CHA.ByteString`, or you need to add an explicit annotation that this should be the type.

Answer (score 4):

The notation `x :: T` reads *expression x has type T*

This may be necessary in the presence of type classes and higher ranked types to enable the compiler to type check the program. For example:

```
main = print . show . read $ "1234"
```

is ambiguous, since the compiler cannot know which of the overloaded `read` functions to use.

In addition, it is possible to narrow the type the compiler would infer. Example:

```
1 :: Int
```

Finally, a type signature like this is often used to make the program more readable.